# Query case sensitive in SQL database without setting database to case sensitive

Tags: sql, database, case, case-sensitive

I have a column IsSeeded with values 'N' and 'NULL' as one of the possibilities
I want to select all records that don't have a 'N' in their field.

when I query

```
select * from database.file where IsSeeded !='N';
```

it also doesn't return the files with values 'NULL'. How can I allow 'NULL' values without having to change my databasepreferences to case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `IS` operator when comparing to `null` values instead of the normal compare operators (`!=`/`=`/`<>`/...)

```
select * from database.file 
where IsSeeded IS NULL;
```

Otherwise the result will be *unknown* for `null` entries and the condition is `false`.

Comment: Ok so if i use following query I get the correct result:
´select * from database.file where IsSeeded !='N' or IsSeeded is Null;´
Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You want the `null` values then use that query. If you want **non** `null`s then use `where IsSeeded IS NOT NULL;`